# Function for generic sum in c

Tags: c

Is it possible to write a generic sum function in C?

I'm trying to write a single sum function that handles any numeric type.

```
double sum(void* myArrayVoidPtr, size_t arrayLength, int arrayType){
    int i;
    double result = 0;

    //The goal is to make this next line depend on arrayType
    //e.g. if(arrayType == UINT16)
    unsigned short* myArrayTypePtr = (unsigned short*) myArrayVoidPtr;

    for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        result += *myArrayTypePtr;
        myArrayTypePtr++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes you can but not like this.

Comment: "Arbitrary" data is not summing up as double. And `+` is not working with "arbitrary" types as well.

Comment: Changed question from "arbitrary" to "any numeric".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to make a generic function in C. Unlike C++, you don't have [templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C%2B%2B%29). Templates allow you to create multiple versions of the same function, that differ by the `type` (i.e - `int`, `float` or any `class`) they "accept". *This means that the function gets compiled more than once*.

C doesn't have templates, but you can write a  a macro for that. This is basically the equivalent of C++'s templates, just less powerful. It will be "inlined" though, not a real function.

```
#define SUM(arr, len, sum) do { int i; for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) sum += arr[i]; } while(0);

int main(void) {
    int i_arr[] = {1,2,3};
    double d_arr[] = {1.5, 2.5, 3.5};
    int sum = 0;
    double d_sum = 0;
    SUM(i_arr, 3, sum)
    SUM(d_arr, 3, d_sum);
    printf("%d, %f\n", sum, d_sum);
    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
6, 7.500000
```

Comment: Why it is impossible? You can make a generic function.

Comment: @haccks How do you define a generic function? You don't have templates in C. The closest thing you can do is a macro, or manually write multiple instances of the same methods.

Comment: You need a structure containing a `union` and a data member for the data type. I don't have time right now otherwise I would post the code.

Comment: @haccks not to rush in, but do you have time now? I am interested in the generic implementation you mentioned. I'd do something like this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b3MMv6

Answer (score 0):

@Mark_Segal is correct, though I think I have a slightly better implementation of the macro, which has a return value like a function would:

```
#define summation(arr, len) ({      \
    __typeof(*arr) sum = 0;         \
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)   \
        sum += arr[i];              \
    sum; })

int main(void) {
    int   isum, iarr[] = { 1, 3, 7 };
    float fsum, farr[] = { 1.5, 3.2, 6.9 };
    isum = summation(iarr,3);
    printf("int sum: %d\n",isum);
    fsum = summation(farr,3);
    printf("float sum: %g\n",fsum);
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
int sum: 11
float sum: 11.6
```

This relies on the existence of the `__typeof` operator (defined in the GNU compiler), which can be replaced with `typeof` (no leading underscores) in some other compilers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using a function and you want to pass an arrayType variable that determines how the array is accessed (as opposed to using typeof) then this might work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

enum type_v {
    UINT8,
    UINT16,
    UINT32,
    UINT64,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE
};

union type_t {
    uint8_t*  uint8Array;
    uint16_t* uint16Array;
    uint32_t* uint32Array;
    uint64_t* uint64Array;
    float*    floatArray;
    double*   doubleArray;
};
    
double sum(void* voidArray, size_t arrayLength, int arrayType)
{
    union type_t arrays;

    switch(arrayType) {
        case UINT8:  arrays.uint8Array  = voidArray; break;
        case UINT16: arrays.uint16Array = voidArray; break;
        case UINT32: arrays.uint32Array = voidArray; break;
        case UINT64: arrays.uint64Array = voidArray; break;
        case FLOAT:  arrays.floatArray  = voidArray; break;
        case DOUBLE: arrays.doubleArray = voidArray; break;
    }

    int i;
    double result = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        switch(arrayType) {
            case UINT8:  result += arrays.uint8Array [i]; break;
            case UINT16: result += arrays.uint16Array[i]; break;
            case UINT32: result += arrays.uint32Array[i]; break;
            case UINT64: result += arrays.uint64Array[i]; break;
            case FLOAT:  result += arrays.floatArray [i]; break;
            case DOUBLE: result += arrays.doubleArray[i]; break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t array[] = {1,2,3,4};
    double result = sum(array, 4, UINT16);
    printf("Sum = %f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/1rjNYJGzg

Note that this isn't really generic although it is extensible to new types, so you could easily extend it to summing individual members of structs that are in an array.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct player {
    char name[32];
    int score;
};

enum type_v {
    UINT8,
    UINT16,
    UINT32,
    UINT64,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE,
    PLAYER
};

union type_t {
    uint8_t*        uint8Array;
    uint16_t*       uint16Array;
    uint32_t*       uint32Array;
    uint64_t*       uint64Array;
    float*          floatArray;
    double*         doubleArray;
    struct player*  playerArray;
};
    
double sum(void* voidArray, size_t arrayLength, int arrayType)
{
    union type_t arrays;

    switch(arrayType) {
        case UINT8:  arrays.uint8Array  = voidArray; break;
        case UINT16: arrays.uint16Array = voidArray; break;
        case UINT32: arrays.uint32Array = voidArray; break;
        case UINT64: arrays.uint64Array = voidArray; break;
        case FLOAT:  arrays.floatArray  = voidArray; break;
        case DOUBLE: arrays.doubleArray = voidArray; break;
        case PLAYER: arrays.playerArray = voidArray; break;
    }

    int i;
    double result = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        switch(arrayType) {
            case UINT8:  result += arrays.uint8Array [i];       break;
            case UINT16: result += arrays.uint16Array[i];       break;
            case UINT32: result += arrays.uint32Array[i];       break;
            case UINT64: result += arrays.uint64Array[i];       break;
            case FLOAT:  result += arrays.floatArray [i];       break;
            case DOUBLE: result += arrays.doubleArray[i];       break;
            case PLAYER: result += arrays.playerArray[i].score; break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    struct player array[] = {{"Bob",1},{"MEl",2},{"Jim",3},{"Ann",4}};
    double result = sum(array, 4, PLAYER);
    printf("Sum = %f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/YfdFwKj0I

Comment: you made the return type `double` tho, that's not very generic.